# How to change component's state using setstate

Tags: reactjs, state, dplyr

React's beginner here!

I have a component with a state, like this:

```
this.state = {
  values: [],
  isloading: true,
  error: false,
  page: 1,
  next: null,
  score: 0,
  seconds: 120,
  finished: false,
  modalopened: false,
  currentcharacter: null,
};
```

I am changing this component's state in the middle of the code, directly, like this:

```
this.state.values[index_value].points = 5
```

And I get a warning, telling me to use "setState".
but how can I access the `values[index].points` using `setState`?

Thanks vm in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to take a look to [React DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) before starting coding.

Anyway, the right way:

```
let arr = [...this.state.values]; // it clones your array without references
arr[index_value].points = 5; // modify only cloned array
this.setState({ values: arr }, () => console.log(this.state)); // set the new array in place of the old one
```

Answer (score 2):

You should never change the state directly.

What you should use is the callback way of `setState`.

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    let newValues = [...prevState.values]
    newValues[index_value].points = 5
    return { values: newValues }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to update state is through setState method, constructor is just an exception to this rule, where we can directly assign state like:

```
this.state = {
  values: [],
  isloading: true,
  error: false,
  page: 1,
  next: null,
  score: 0,
  seconds: 120,
  finished: false,
  modalopened: false,
  currentcharacter: null,
};
```

After this assignation, you should always use setState function to update state, if your state updation is dependent on previous value of state, you should pass previous state to this function i.e  incrementting a number by 1, updating true/ false flags etc.